# How can I remove white spaces between words?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have text `A B   c` in a spreadhsheet cell.

How can I remove the whitespaces? `=Trim` is for leading and closing whitespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\s", "")` where A1 is your cell with spaces. It uses a regular expression to match any whitespace character, including spaces, tabs, and newlines. If you only want to remove spaces, then use `=REGEXREPLACE(A1, " ", "")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Substitute function like this `=SUBSTITUTE(B3, " ", "")`. Hope it helps.